# Why I cannot deploy my app to docker successfully

Tags: docker

I try to deploy my app to Docker. But I meet some problem with this process.

Here is my folder structure:

- Controls
- Model
- Semantic-UI-Master
- src
- Dockerfile
- .dockerignore
- package json

Here is my code in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.15.1
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm cache clean --force && npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

I got this error:

```
 ---> Running in ff6c4bf4ce8e
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
The command '/bin/sh -c npm cache clean --force && npm install' returned a non-zero code: 137
```

Any ideas and suggestions? Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 2):

Error code `137` means you have [OOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory) issues. This happens, because MacOS imposes RAM limits on Docker, as opposed to Linux where a container can eat [as much RAM as it wants](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#understand-the-risks-of-running-out-of-memory).

Since `npm install` can consume a lot of resources, you have to increase your memory limit for Docker in the [Docker advanced settings](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#advanced).

*Additional references*:

- [Docker for Mac should honor the memory limits](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2234)
- [Prevent Docker containers from crashing with error 137 - by Bobcares](https://bobcares.com/blog/error-137-docker/)

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add line "`RUN ls`" in your Dockerfile after "`COPY . .`" and rebuild the image with flag "**--no-cache**", check the console output to see if your files is copied into the image or not. If it does not open the **.dockerignore** file to see if you are ignoring "**package.json**" file or any file that you want to copy.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much! Let me give a try!

Comment: I got this red line `npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.`

Comment: The file is complete and it is there

Comment: `The command '/bin/sh -c ls && npm cache clean --force && npm install' returned a non-zero code: 130` Same error

Comment: I use mac os. Mac book pro

Comment: Oh if the file is still there, and the different error now. Technically you don't have to clean the cache if your source code is clean. Try removing your RUN command and CMD command, build a static image, run it and exec into using "**docker exec -it <container_name_or_id> bash**" and cd into "**/usr/src/app**" try to debug from the inside by calling "**npm cache clean --force**" then "**npm install**" to see which is causing the error.

Comment: I think @emix is right, try his solution to increase the RAM usage limitation for docker.

Answer (score 1):

From searching in the internet most people says npm error 137 is caused by lack of memory.

What you can try do?

1. run npm install outside the docker build and then just copy the dependencies
2. Increase the Docker Desktop runtime memory as explained in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#advanced): Preferences -> Advanced -> Memory

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: I think I can try to build images through the DockerHub Github API

Comment: They have access to build remotely